# Incorrect localization of markers on map. Strange behaviour of markers on the map

Tags: android, osmdroid

I works with OSMdroid. I  extended the Overlay class  and I overridden  the draw method to my needs. And I have a problem with placing of markers. When I display them for the  first time they have wrong location. But when I start zooming they move and after couple of zooms they have correct localization.

Here is my code:

```
protected final Rect mRect = new Rect();
protected Point mScreenPts = new Point();

@Override
protected void draw(Canvas c, MapView osmv, boolean shadow) {
    Projection pj = osmv.getProjection();

    synchronized (mInternalItemList) {
        if (shadow && !mInternalItemList.isEmpty()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < mInternalItemList.size(); i++) {
            CustomizedItem customized = mInternalItemList.get(i);

                pj.toMapPixels(new GeoPoint(customized.getLatitude(),
                                customized.getLongitude()), mScreenPts);            

                boundToHotspot(customized.getDrawable(), HotspotPlace.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER);

                Drawable draw = customized.getDrawable();

                draw.copyBounds(mRect);
                draw.setBounds(mRect.left + mScreenPts.x, mRect.top + mScreenPts.y, 
                           mRect.right + mScreenPts.x, mRect.bottom + mScreenPts.y);

                draw.draw(c);
                draw.setBounds(mRect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maps v1 is no longer supported, you should try using maps v2

Comment: Maps v1 is still supported in osmdroid.

Comment: i use OSMdroid 3.0.10, how to deal with this ?

Comment: Try using ItemizedIconOverlay and take a look at the OpenStreetMapViewer example project.